# SQL Server Transactions - how to use them

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have software that has to write "packets" of goods to a database. It must write either all of them, or none, in case of an error. To do this we use transactions. Begin transactions, N-hundred inserts, commit transaction. So far so good.

Now there are two different scenarios:

1. there is a bug in a query for whatever reason or the database stops responding while inserting: the transaction is open, and requires a rollback.
2. the entire software crashes during the insert, and the transaction remains open.

In these cases I need to be able to recover. I was thinking to simply kill all rows that are returned by this query:

`SELECT spid FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran > 0;`

But this kills the connection if the situation is the first one above. And a Rollback does not work if it the situation 2 above.

what would be the proper way to recover from the above situations, and be sure that there are no open transactions?

Comment: If your session uses `set xact_abort on` it will rollback on app crash. The topic is too big to answer in a single question, but there are a large number of articles available which will explain the intricacies of error handling and transactions in SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK thank you, should i simply add that to the query before the `begin transaction`? what is the criteria for the rollback? is there a timeout or something like that?

Comment: I'll point you to the official docs for that info,

Comment: This is the bible of error handling in SQL Server: https://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html

Comment: @DaleK I think that's the old one - the newer one https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern is more up-to-date and the link there goes straight to a template for TRY/CATCH and TRANSACTION blocks

Comment: THank you! that workded great. Dalek, could you please post it as answer so i can accept it?